# JQuery get child all data attributes

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following list:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="click">
            <span>click here</span>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li data-dataAttribute="1"></li>
            <li data-dataAttribute="3"></li>
            <li data-dataAttribute="7"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In this case, I want to fetch all the data elements below the `ul` in the individual `li` elements and add them to a list.

I have tried the following:

```
$("#fileSystem").on('click', '.click', function () {
    var attributes = $(this > 'ul').children().data('dataAttribute');
    debugger;
});
```

This does however not work, which I can't seem to work out. I suspect that it may has to do with the selector.

Comment: `$(this > 'ul')` - What do you expect this to do? A `HTMLDivElement` is never greater than a string o.O

Comment: Break up the chaining an do the steps one at a time. Evaluate the result in the debugger.

Comment: wow, you are correct. That's stupid.

Comment: can you tell what you want. unclear with your statement

Comment: `$(this > 'ul')` does not work. this is an element, not a selector. `$(this).children('ul')` is what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find child elements, you can use one of:

```
$("> ul", this)
$(this).find("ul")
```

Within your click handler, `this` will be the "click here" div.  A selector using `>` means find the child elements, but in your HTML the `ul` is not a child element of `this` (click here), so won't work.

So you need to find the *next* `ul`, not a child `ul` and `>` isn't used for that.

If the `ul` is the next element, then you can use a simple `.next()` otherwise you'll need to locate it using some other method.

You can then extract the data using `.map`

Note that `data-xyz` must be lowercase, otherwise `$("li").data("xyz")` won't find it.

Putting these together gives you:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".click", function() {
    var data = $(this).next().find("li").map(function() { 
        return $(this).data("dataattribute")}
    ).toArray()
    console.log(data)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="click">
            <span>click here</span>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li data-dataattribute="1"></li>
            <li data-dataattribute="3"></li>
            <li data-dataattribute="7"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: _"...must be lowercase, otherwise `$("li").data("xyz")` won't find it."_ - So any other library (or vanilla JS) would work with `data-xYzAbC`?

Comment: I just tried on the other answer and `.attr("data-xYz")` will work, but won't make use of jquery's caching and coercion - `.data()` will give you a matching type (int's above) while `.attr()` is always a string.  But to answer the question - any other library will do whatever that library does and vanilla js doesn't use `.data()` it uses `.dataset` which converts `-` to uppercase, eg `data-x-yz` becomes `.dataset.xYz`

Comment: It's totally irrelevant if this is jQuery or lodash or whatever... `data-*` attributes have to be, [per definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/dom.html#element-attrdef-global-data), all lowercase.

Comment: @Andreas so what was your question?  Or rather, what was the *point* of your question?    Saying .data() won't find mixed case has *no implication* that any other library will work.  Why not just add a comment to clarify beyond the scope of the question and answer that they must be lowercase in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try map:

Please note your data attributes MUST be all lowercase

```js
$(function() {
  $("#fileSystem").on('click', '.click', function() {
    const list = $(this)
        .closest("li") // or .next()
        .find("ul>li[data-dataattribute]")
        .map((i,li) => $(li).attr("data-dataattribute")).get()
    console.log(list)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fileSystem">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="click">
        <span>click here</span>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li data-dataattribute="1"></li>
        <li data-dataattribute="3"></li>
        <li data-dataattribute="7"></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Just an observation: if you use `.attr("data-xyz")` you will always get a string, if you use `.data("xyz")` then jquery will attempt to give you the correct data type.  This may not always work, so you can decided which method to use; knowing of the two options is the key.

Comment: Interestingly, unlike `.data()`, `.attr()` is case *in*sensitive, so they can be mixed case and can even be different case on different elements.